# add a link a in controller instead of in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I know it's unusual to have a link a controller but in my case I have to have it there. 
here is my code: 
**Controller**:

```
    switch (Auth.AuthenticationResult)
                        {
                            case AuthenticationResult.Failed:
                                Error = "Incorrect password. Click here if you forgot your credentials";
    ModelState.AddModelError("", Error);
```

I would like to have the Click Here as a link to another controller.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain the "have to have it there".  In your controller

```
ViewBag.AuthenticationResult = Auth.AuthenticationResult
```

then in the view

```
@if (ViewBag.AuthenticationResult == AuthenticationResult.Failed)
{
    <span>Incorrect password. </span>
    @Html.ActionLink("Click here", "ActionName", "ControllerName")
    <span>if you forgot your credentials</span>
}
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct. But I just want to point out that you will have to use @html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "ActionName", "ControllerName")
) to correctly have the link working. If you can edit you answer and add my comment, that will be awesome for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `RedirectToAction()` inside your switch, assuming the switch is in a controller class.  The `action` that you redirect to would be associated with a  view which has the link to wherever it is you want your link to go to.

This would take the form of:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        switch (Auth.AuthenticationResult)
                    {
                        case AuthenticationResult.Failed:
                            return RedirectToAction("NewView", "ErrorController");
                    }
        return View();
    }
}
```

In this scenario you send the user to the action "NewView" located in the controller "ErrorController".  Your "NewView" view, can then be setup to handle this particular error with a custom message and link for the user to proceed elsewhere.

More information on `RedirectToAction` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: It's not working unfortunately. it just print the whole namespace for the RedirectToAction (System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult). Plus I need to have a text for the link. If I was in a View, the equivalent of what I want to achieve would have used @htm.ActionLink("MyLinkText", "Action", "Controller")

Comment: @MikeLarche I updated to try and provide more clarity on this concept.